# Following the Docker getting started pages and I get an error on Centos 7.4 when running their Python test image

Tags: docker

I am following the Getting Started page on the Docker website, I am having trouble with the command `docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello`.

I have copied the text perfectly to create the Dockerfile and the app.py/requiremtns.txt files.
The error I get is:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint zealous_lumiere (fba612f70c8dc759e8acce05d185e6c362a03e0f060601cd5ef528d692247772): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:4000: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I am running Centos 7.4, Docker version 17.12.0-ce

I have already used the command:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Error message Port Number: 4000 is already used by the VM or System. the docker is unable to allocate 4000 port to your application. Try to use the different port number instead of 4000 as the command given below.

```
     docker run -p 5000:80 friendlyhello
```

Or check your machine which application is using port 4000 and stop that application and try to run your command. It will work.